# How do I create a button in c++ with my own custom image?

Tags: c++, bitmap, hwnd, wndproc

I've been looking for a way to make a picture a button in c++ for a *few hours* now.. I've found stuff on using bitmaps, what what i am currently using to display the image is GDI+, because i want to use jpg/png files.

This is how i created my Image with gdiplus:

```
void Example_DrawImage(HDC hdc) {

           Graphics graphics(hdc);

           image = Image::FromFile(L"Path:/To/Image");

           myBitmap = dynamic_cast<Bitmap*>(image);

           Pen pen(Color(0, 0, 0, 0), 2);

           graphics.DrawImage(image, 10, 10);

}
```

I converted that to a bitmap with:

```
myBitmap = dynamic_cast<Bitmap*>(image);
```

Then, in WM_CREATE I created a button which it's standard style is a Windows XP Button:

```
button = CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Hello"),
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_BITMAP,
            10, 10, /* x & y*/  80, 25, /*width & height*/
            hwnd, (HMENU) 1, hInstance, NULL
        );
```

`button` is globally defined as `HWND button;`

All I want is to have a button that is a jpg picture. I tried doing it manually by seeing if a mouse click was inside a certain area, but I could not find a way to find the position of the Image.

Comment: Have you got anything in the way of reference that uses the newer Microsoft technologies like [ATL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Template_Library)?

Comment: No I don't believe I am using ATL @tadman

Comment: I think that's why you're having trouble here. Apart from the use of GDI+ this looks like the Windows 3.1 way of writing code in C. It's an uphill battle without support.

Comment: So should I start using ATL? How would I go about doing that? @tadman

Comment: It's worth checking around with Windows C++ devs as to what they do. I know Visual Studio tries to coach you on how to set up a new desktop application project, so it's worth touching base there first. MSDN has an incredible wealth of information on the subject as well. Most apps use something like MFC, ATL, or Qt as a basis for their code.

Comment: Alright, thanks! @tadman